# How to autocomplete select option in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, autocomplete

I'm trying to make a select option in CodeIgniter, and want to make it autocomplete fill. How do I do that?

This is my code:

Model:

```
public function get_nama_customer(){
        $data = array();
        $query = $this->db->get('tabel_customer');
        if($query->num_rows() > 0){
            foreach($query->result_array() as $row){
                $data[] = $row;

            }
        }

        $query->free_result();
        return $data;
    }
```

Controller:

```
public function add_data()
    {
        $this->load->model('model_tabel_material');
        $data['tabel_customer'] = $this->model_tabel_material->get_nama_customer();
        $this->load->view('datamaster/tabel_material/v_add_material', $data);
    }

public function do_add()
    {
        $nama_customer  = $_POST['nama_customer'];

        $data_add = array(
            "nama_customer"     => $nama_customer,
        );

        $temp = $this->model_tabel_material->insert_data('tabel_material', $data_add);
        if($temp >=1){
            redirect('tabel_material/controller_tabel_material/index');
        }
    }
```

View:

```
<select class="form-control" name="nama_customer" id="nama_customer" required>
                                                <?php if(count($tabel_customer)){ ?>
                                                    <option value=''>--Pilih Customer--</option>
                                                    <?php foreach ($tabel_customer as $list){ ?>
                                                        <?php
                                                            echo "<option value='".$list['nama_customer']."'>".$list['nama_customer']."</option>";
                                                        ?>
                                                    <?php } ?>
                                                <?php } ?>
                                            </select>
```

Comment: this code is fine now, if any issue is facing please make sure the error is mentioned in the comment

Comment: hi Justin, thanks for helping me. the code actualy work in select option, but it doesn't run in autocomplete field. i want to change the code so it can make an autofill when i type a word in the option field. what code should i change or add?

Comment: this question is way too broad: please read http://mfikri.com/en/blog/codeigniter-autocomplete and other tutorials